# How to change working directory of container_command in Elastic Beanstalk custom platform

Tags: elastic-beanstalk

The working directory to execute `container_command` defined in the application's .ebextensions is `/tmp` on the sample custom platform [NodePlatform_Ubuntu](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html), while I expected it to be the staging directory as stated in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands).

How can I change the working directory to the staging (the root of unzipped source code) directory?

This is `.ebextensions/foo.config` of the test app to see the working directory.

```
container_commands:
  10-test:
    command: env
```

Then, this is its output in /var/log/eb-activity.log.

```
[2018-04-30T04:26:54.394Z] INFO  [19153] - [Application update test-app-4@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_cocci_custom_eb_test/Command 10-test] : Starting activity...
[2018-04-30T04:26:54.399Z] INFO  [19153] - [Application update test-app-4@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_cocci_custom_eb_test/Command 10-test] : Completed activity. Result:
  PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
  PWD=/tmp
  SHLVL=1
  HOME=/root
  EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER=true
  _=/usr/bin/env

[2018-04-30T04:26:54.618Z] INFO  [19153] - [Application update test-app-4@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_cocci_custom_eb_test/Command 20-check-process] : Starting activity...
```

Comment: It seems the working directory is defined by `app_staging_dir`. `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir` returns `/tmp`. But now, how can I set `app_staging_dir`?

Answer (score 0):

I could change it by specifying it in platform.yaml file of the custom platform.

```
container:
  app_staging_dir: "/var/app/staging"
```

The log of container_command;

```
[2018-04-30T09:49:14.452Z] INFO  [1482]  - [Application deployment test-app-4@2/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_cocci_custom_eb_test/Command 10-test] : Completed activity. Result:
  PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
  PWD=/var/app/staging
  SHLVL=1
  HOME=/root
  EB_IS_COMMAND_LEADER=false
  _=/usr/bin/env
```

I'm guessing that other options can be specified in the same way.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxx:~$ sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container --output YAML
---
app_staging_dir: "/var/app/staging"
instance_port: '80'
config_staging_dir: "/tmp"
common_log_list:
- "/var/log/eb-activity.log"
log_group_name_prefix: "/aws/elasticbeanstalk"
source_bundle: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle"
```